# sqldeveloper procedure from select

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedures

Hi I have select like this

```
SELECT
  ADDRESSES.PHONENUMBER1,
  ADDRESSES.PHONENUMBER2,
  FIRMS.NAME,
  ADDRESSES.COUNTRY,
  ADDRESSES.EMAIL,
  ADDRESSES.RECIPIENT
FROM ADDRESSES
INNER JOIN FIRMS
ON FIRMS.RESIDENCEADDRESS_ID = ADDRESSES.ID
WHERE (replace(REPLACE(ADDRESSES.PHONENUMBER1, ' ', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%123456789%')
OR (replace(REPLACE(ADDRESSES.PHONENUMBER1, ' ', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%123456789%')
```

And I would like make a procedure and the result be

name, address, email,

also need help with replace 123456789 wit correct ask

thank you

Comment: What did you try ?  You should read http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Take a look at Oracle Create Proc Documentation - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm. Start working on it, once you encounter an error or don't understand something then we can help.

Comment: I am not sql specialist and the IN and OUT NOCOPY explanation do not understand. And where = what ? In my select I was where like %number% or like %number% This not fit to explanation SQL Reference so I ask you experts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..this works, but if someone knew something that could be improved. Let me know

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST
(
in_ANI in VARCHAR2,
out_all out VARCHAR2
)


AS
    fName VARCHAR2 (40) := '';
    aemail VARCHAR2 (40) := '';


BEGIN

out_all := '';

  SELECT FIRMS.NAME, ADDRESSES.EMAIL
  into fName, aemail
  FROM ADDRESSES
  INNER JOIN FIRMS
  ON FIRMS.RESIDENCEADDRESS_ID = ADDRESSES.ID
  WHERE (replace(REPLACE(ADDRESSES.PHONENUMBER1, ' ', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%'||in_ANI||'%')
  OR (replace(REPLACE(ADDRESSES.PHONENUMBER2, ' ', ''), '-', '') LIKE '%'||in_ANI||'%');


out_ALL := 'Firm:' || fName || '|Email:' || aemail;

    exception
      when TOO_MANY_ROWS then 
        out_ALL := ('Firm:Too Many firms for this phone');

      when NO_DATA_FOUND then 
        out_ALL := ('Firm:No firms for this number');

      when others then 
        raise_application_error(-20011,'Unknown Exception');


END TEST;
```